# FFmpeg - concatenate variable length intro / outro fixed segments and separate audio track

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create an app which generates a video based on 3 main parts: -

1. **Intro** - Variable length video (~ 20 to 30 seconds long)
2. **Segments** - 3 clips from a "segments video" - this is a fixed length video (always 400 seconds) which contains 100 separate videos all precisely 4 seconds in length e.g. *"segment 1"* is from `0` to `4` seconds and *"segment 3*" is from `8` to `12` seconds.
3. **Outro** - Variable length video (~ 10 to 20 seconds long)

The user picks the intro, segments and outro from a list of videos and the app concatenates these together (and extracts `3` segments at random).  The user also picks an audio file which plays for the entire video. The generated file should look something like the following: -

#### GENERATED VIDEO

```
VIDEO   | Intro (20 - 30) |  Seg 1 (4) |  Seg 2 (4) |  Seg 3 (4) |  Outro (10 - 20)  |
--------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+
AUDIO   |        Audio track which spans full video (e.g. 4 minutes long) ...        |
```

I have been able to hack the following together using `ffmpeg` (which works): -

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -i audio/audio-19.m4a \
  -i videos/intro/intro-23.mkv \
  -i videos/segments/segments-88.mkv \
  -i videos/outro/outro-12.mkv \
  -filter_complex \
    "[1:v]trim=0:30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
    [0:a]atrim=0:30,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
    [2:v]trim=20:24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
    [0:a]atrim=30:34,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
    [2:v]trim=60:64,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
    [0:a]atrim=34:38,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
    [2:v]trim=132:136,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
    [0:a]atrim=38:42,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; \
    [3:v]trim=0:20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4]; \
    [0:a]atrim=42:62,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a4]; \
    [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3][v4][a4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[out]" \
  -map "[out]" generated.mkv
```

However, there are 2 problems with this solution: -

1. I've had to define the length of the *intro* video (`[1:v]trim=0:30 ...`) and the outro video (`[3:v]trim=0:20 ...`) - these are variable and would be preferable if I could simply concat the entire video.
2. Each of the audio tracks are trimmed (using a running total from each video length) e.g. `[0:a]atrim=0:30 ...` => `[0:a]atrim=30:34 ...` => `[0:a]atrim=34:38 ...` => etc.  Would be much easier if it simply said - "here's the audio track - trim depending on the length of the generated video"

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much reading, trial and error I've got a nicer solution: -

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -i audio/audio-19.m4a \
  -i videos/intro/intro-23.mkv \
  -i videos/segments/segments-88.mkv \
  -i videos/outro/outro-12.mkv \
  -filter_complex \
    "[2:v]trim=20:24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s1]; \
     [2:v]trim=60:64,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s2]; \
     [2:v]trim=132:136,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s3]; \
     [1][s1][s2][s3][3]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[outv]" \
  -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -shortest generated.mkv
```

With this solution I only trim the segment video (e.g. `[2:v]trim=20:24`) and reset the timestamp to zero (`setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s1]` - see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide on why that is necessary).  This is done 3 times for the 3 segments.

The `concat` complex filter then *only concatenates video*.

```
[1][s1][s2][s3][3]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[outv]
```

It grabs the video from the intro video (`[1]`), the newly created segment clip videos (`[s1][s2][s3]`) and finally the outro video (`[3]`) and joins them together.  However, it ignores audio i.e. `concat=n=5:v=1:a=0` *(compared to `concat=n=5:v=1:a=1` in the previous solution)* and saves this to a new video only stream called `[outv]`.

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat for more info on concatenation.

Finally we map the video using this new concatenated *video only stream* `"[outv]"` and the audio from the 1st input file (`0:a`) i.e.

```
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -shortest generated.mkv
```

The audio track is assumed to be longer than the length of the generated video so the `-shortest` argument trims the output to the *shortest* stream (i.e. the length of the generated video).

This helped me understand the `-map` command -
 https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options